# NMinimize problem again

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Following up my previous question which got great replies, I am now trying to do

```
NMinimize[{1/2 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n] - Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])],  n > 4}, n]
```

It gives me the answer `0.328427`.

```
NMinimize[{1/2 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n] - Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])],  n > 5}, n]
```

gives me `-0.0358984` and so it goes on if I change the range or add upper bounds for n as well.

Is there any way to get a minimum with any confidence?

My guess is that the true minimum for n > 4 is 2*(sqrt(3)-2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, *visualize* your function before you do anything:

```
Plot[1/2 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n] - Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])], {n, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Plot]

The function is discontinuous and each time it jumps, it hits a new local infimum.  Where are the jumps?  Exactly where `Ceiling` does; that is, whenever its argument is an integer.  I will confine this analysis to positive $n$ and find the values of $n$ where it is potentially discontinuous by equating the argument's value with an unknown integer $m$:

```
Reduce[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n]) == m  && m \[Element] Integers && n >= 0, {n}]
```

> $m\in \text{Integers}\ \&\&\  m\geq 0\ \&\&\ n==\frac{1}{2} \left(m+m^2\right)$

We can plot the pieces of this function independently, using the integer $m$ to index the regions where it's continuous:

```
Show[base = Table[
  Plot[1/2 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n] - m, {n, 1/2 (m - 1 + (m - 1)^2),  1/2 (m + m^2)},
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Hue[m/5]}], 
 {m, 1, 5}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot]

In a similar way we can index these new *local* minima by *m*:

```
min[m_] := Evaluate@First@Minimize[{1/2 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n] - m, 
  1/2 (m - 1 + (m - 1)^2) < n <=  1/2 (m + m^2) && m >= 1}, n];
? min
```

> $\min [\text{m$\_$}]\text{:=}\text{Piecewise}\left[\left\{\left\{-\frac{1}{2},m==1\right\},\left\{\frac{1}{2} (1-2 m)+\frac{\sqrt{-2 m+2 m^2}}{\sqrt{2}},m>1\right\}\right\},\infty \right]$

That answers the conjecture in the question by giving **a formula for how these local minima depend on $m$**, whence on $n$ via substitution:

```
min[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])] // Simplify
```

> $\begin{array}{ll}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{ll}
>  -\frac{1}{2} & \sqrt{1+8 n}==3 \\
>  1-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1+8 n}+\sqrt{1+2 n-\sqrt{1+8 n}} & \sqrt{1+8 n}>3 \\
>  \infty  & \text{True}
> \end{array}
> \end{array}$

A plot of this function serves to check the work, remembering that $m$ must be obtained as the *ceiling* of the values:

```
minima = Plot[min[Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])]], {n, 1, 15}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Black}];
Show[base, pts, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot 3]

The minimum depends on the lower limit imposed on $n$ and, as that lower limit increases, appears to increase.  It would be asking a lot of *Mathematica* to compute this limit literally, as in

```
Limit[min[Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])]], n -> Infinity]
```

(and sure enough, its output is uninformative), but it's not necessary: this limit must coincide with the limit obtained without restricting the argument of `min` to integral values:

```
Limit[min[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])], n -> Infinity]
```

> $0$

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
NMinimize[{1/2 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n] - Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])], 
  n > 4, n \[Element] Integers}, n]
(* {0.241657, {n -> 7}} *)

NMinimize[{1/2 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n] - Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])], 
  n > 5, n \[Element] Integers}, n]
(* {0.241657, {n -> 7}} *)
```

You can check the above with a plot :

```
DiscretePlot[1/2 + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n] - Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])], {n,1, 10}]
```

[image: plot]